# Kernel driver for trackpoint on Lenovo Thinkpad 13

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, udev, input, thinkpad

On other ThinkPads I've succesfully configured the trackpoint with udev using [this method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37824/what-is-the-best-way-to-configure-a-thinkpads-trackpoint/553926) but on my new Lenovo Thinkpad 13 this isn't possible:

This command:

```
find /sys/devices/platform/i8042 -name name | xargs grep -Fl TrackPoint | sed 's/\/input\/input[0-9]*\/name$//'
```

... outputs:

```
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1
```

But neither that folder nor any of the subfolders contain the files `sensitivity` and `speed`. Same issue has been confirmed by [ThinkPad 13 owner on another kernel and distro](https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/4jku4c/configuring_trackpoint_on_thinkpad_13/d37ujw9).

I'm guessing that the kernel driver doesn't properly detect that the device is in fact a trackpoint. This assumption is backed by [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/component/input/4932/input%3AElantechPS/2TrackPoint/) (not very informative) hardware evaluation from Ubuntu.

An alternative method for configuring the trackpoint is using xinput but as my distro - Debian - har switched to libinput this is a headache of its own due to [this bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1200717) (that's apparently affecting Fedora, too.)

I would really like to be able to configure the trackpoint by way of udev and the method above but I don't know how to debug further.

Does Ubuntu's hardware evaluation mean that it's an unsolvable hardware issue?

Or is it a kernel bug?

How can I know?

Some system output:

```
# uname -a
Linux debian 4.5.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.5.3-2 (2016-05-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux

# xinput list
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Elantech PS/2 TrackPoint                  id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                       id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard                 id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                                id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                   id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                                id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                                id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera                           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard                id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                      id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]

# xinput list-props 14
Device 'Elantech PS/2 TrackPoint':
    Device Enabled (136):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (138): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Accel Speed (274): 1.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (275): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (276):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (277):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (278):   1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (279):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (280):   0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (258): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (259):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (260):    0, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (281): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (282): 0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (283):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (284):   0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (285):   0, 0, 1
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (286): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (287): 274
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (288):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (289):    0
    Device Node (261):  "/dev/input/event1"
    Device Product ID (262):    2, 14
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (290):   <no items>
    libinput Horizonal Scroll Enabled (263):    1
```